# Find Tangent Points of Circle and Two Lines in First Quadrant

Tags: math, geometry, wolfram-mathematica, computational-geometry, sage

I need to define explicit expressions to find the points (x1,y1) and (x2,y2), which are the two tangent points of a circle with radius r (known) and two lines (equations known). The center of the circle (x0,y0) is *not* know and *not* needed. See picture below.

[image]

In my case, I have the following conditions:

1. problem in first quadrant: x>0, y>0
2. line y=m1*x+b1 with m1<=0, b1>=0
3. line y=m2*x+b2 with m2 < m1, b2>b1
4. circle centre above y=m1*x+b1, so y0>y1
5. circle centre at r.h.s. of y=m2*x+b2, so x0>x2
6. circle tangent to line y=m1*x+b1, so (y1-y0)/(x1-x0)=-1/m1
7. circle tangent to line y=m2*x+b2, so (y2-y0)/(x2-x0)=-1/m2

I computed the following:

```
x1, y1, x2, y2 = var('x1, y1, x2, y2')   # tangent points
m1, b1, m2, b2 = var('m1, b1, m2, b2')   # lines' eqn
x0, y0, r = var('x0, y0, r')             # cirsle's eqn

eq1 = (x1 - x0)^2 + (y1 - y0)^2 - r^2 == 0
eq2 = (x2 - x0)^2 + (y2 - y0)^2 - r^2 == 0
eq3 = y1 - m1*x1 - b1 == 0
eq4 = y2 - m2*x2 - b2 == 0
eq5 = (y1-y0)/(x1-x0) == -1/m1
eq6 = (y2-y0)/(x2-x0) == -1/m2

# unknown: x0,y0,x1,y1,x2,y2
#   known: m1,b1,m2,b2,r

solve([eq1,eq2,eq3,eq4,eq5,eq6,
       x1>0,y1>0,x2>0,y2>0,
       m1<=0,b1>=0,m2<m1,b2>b1,
       x0>x2,y0>y1,r>0],x0,y0,x1,y1,x2,y2)
```

Why is this not enough to define the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Computing `x1`, `y1`, `x2` and `y2` as unknowns**

```
Clear[m1, x1, b1, m2, x2, b2, r, x0]
y1 = m1 x1 + b1;
y2 = m2 x2 + b2;
s1 = r/Sqrt[1 + 1/m1^2];
s2 = r/Sqrt[1 + 1/m2^2];

x0 = x0 /. FullSimplify@Solve[
     m1 x0 + b1 + (s1 (-(1/m1)) - s1 m1) == 
      m2 x0 + b2 + (s2 (-(1/m2)) - s2 m2), x0][[1]]
```

> (-b1 + b2 + Sqrt[1 + 1/m1^2] m1 r - Sqrt[1 + 1/m2^2] m2 r)/(m1 - m2)

```
y0 = FullSimplify[m1 x0 + b1 + (s1 (-(1/m1)) - s1 m1)]
```

> (b2 m1 - m2 (b1 + 
>       m1 (-Sqrt[1 + 1/m1^2] + Sqrt[1 + 1/m2^2]) r))/(m1 - m2)

```
x1 = x1 /. FullSimplify@
   Solve[{(x1 - x0)^2 + (y1 - y0)^2 == r^2}, x1][[1]]
```

> (r + m1 m2 r - 
>    Sqrt[1 + 1/m1^2] m1 (b1 - b2 + Sqrt[1 + 1/m2^2] m2 r))/(Sqrt[
>    1 + 1/m1^2] m1 (m1 - m2))

```
x2 = x2 /. FullSimplify@
   Solve[{(x2 - x0)^2 + (y2 - y0)^2 == r^2}, x2][[1]]
```

> (b2 - b1 (1 + m2^2) + Sqrt[1 + 1/m1^2] m1 r + 
>    m2 (b2 m2 - (Sqrt[1 + 1/m2^2] + 
>          m1 (-Sqrt[1 + 1/m1^2] + Sqrt[1 + 1/m2^2]) m2) r))/((m1 - 
>      m2) (1 + m2^2))

Testing with values

```
m1 = -0.28; b1 = 1.64; m2 = -1.08; b2 = 3.84;
r = 3.9062658021579098;

{x1, y1}
{x2, y2}
```

> {3.81302, 0.572355}
>
> {2., 1.68}

```
Show[Plot[
  {m1 x + b1,
   m1 x + b1 + (s1 (-(1/m1)) - s1 m1),
   m2 x + b2,
   m2 x + b2 + (s2 (-(1/m2)) - s2 m2)}, {x, 0, 10},
  PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {0, 10}}, AspectRatio -> 1],
 Graphics[Circle[{x0, y0}, r]]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your approach @ChrisDegnen, however 'x2' must b computed as an unknown.

Comment: @J.Serra I don't think you can have formulae for `x1`, `y1`, `x2` *and* `y2` because the circle could be any size sitting tangentially on the two lines.  One of the points needs to be an anchor parameter, the others are defined in terms of that point and the two tangential line equations.

Comment: Hi @ChrisDegnen, the size of the circle is given by its radius r, which is known.

Comment: @J.Serra I have added a solution which uses `r` as an input.

Comment: @J.Serra Thanks for the accept.  It was an interesting exercise.

Answer (score 2):

I know neither the details of Sage (which I think your code is in) or Mathematica at all, but I can point out some difficulties.

First, I believe you need to "catch" the mathematics variables you define into the language's variables. So you may need

```
x1, y1, x2, y2 = var('x1, y1, x2, y2')   # tangent points
m1, b1, m2, b2 = var('m1, b1, m2, b2')   # lines' eqn
x0, y0, r = var('x0, y0, r')        # cirsle's eqn
```

Next, you put all of your equations into one `solve` command. As you can see from your diagram, no point is on the circle and on both lines, but you try to find all points satisfying all your equations simultaneously. You should split your single `solve` into two commands, one for each line.

Next, there is nothing in your requirements that make your lines tangent to your given curve. For a mostly arbitrary circle and line, there may be no, one, or two intersection points, and it is extremely unlikely that exactly one point would arise. You need a restriction that each line is tangent to the curve. That restriction is moderately difficult to program and seems no easier than just finding the intersection point. Are you sure that the approach you are using is a good one for your problem?

There are additional difficulties in ensuring that the tangent points are in the first quadrant, but that is less important than the other difficulties.

Finally, there is nothing in your code to suggest that your known values are `m1, b1, m2, b2, r` and you want `x0, y0` to drop out of the final expressions. (You do state that you want expressions for `x1, y1, x2, y2`.) I don't know how to do that in Sage or Mathematica.

---

The mathematics problem involved is not all that difficult. The point `(x0, y0)` must lie on the lines parallel to your given lines and a distance of `r` from the lines. That results in four points for `(x0, y0)`. For each of those you find the points on your given lines closest to those points `(x0, y0)`. That yields four points total, then you just pick the ones in the first quadrant. Another, faster, trigonometric approach is to find the angle between the two given lines, then you can use trig to find the distance of your desired points from the intersection point then find the points.

Are you sure you need Sage/Mathematica to do that for you?

Comment: Thanks for the comments @RoryDaulton, I updated mt conditions accordingly and included 5 and 6. They require that the circle is tangent to both lines. The problem is still undefined. I am after expressions to find x1, y1, x2, y2 so that I can compute them.

Comment: @J.Serra: Those additional equations do not make the lines tangent to the circle, they just make the points `(x1, y1)` and `(x2, y2)` on the circle. There is no idea of *tangency* in those equations. In fact, `eq5` is equivalent to `eq1` and `eq6` is equivalent to `eq2`. Rather, you could state that the line segment from the center to each point is perpendicular to the line. Also, you did not address my other issues or answer any of my questions.

Comment: That's correct @RoryDaulton, eqns 5 and 6 were redundant. As you suggested, I redefined them so that it's stated that the drawn radii are perpendicular to the two lines, hence these are tangent to the circle. Regarding your other comments: (i) the definition of variables was correct both I included your statement for clarity; (ii) I don't see how I can solve the problem using 2 systems as the circle needs to be defined by both lines simultaneously; (iii) I think now I have the correct conditions on tagency requirements;

Comment: (iv) I think my approach is correct since my objective is to have 4 explicit expressions to define x1, y1, x2, y2 given any 2 lines and circle with radius r (under the conditions stated); (v) I think the conditions on xi>0, yi>0 (i=1,2) ensure we are in the first quadrant; (vi) I believe I correctly formulated the problem to get x1, y1, x2, y2 from SageMath (but I'm not an experienced user of math software).

Answer (score 2):

The parallels to the two given lines at distance R intersect at the center of the circle. When you have found this point, you project it on the two original lines.

These operations have simple analytical expressions.

---

Let the two lines be `a'x+b'y+c'=0`, `a"x+b"y+c"=0` where `a'²+b'²=1, a"²+b"²=1` (this is a slightly more general form than your equations).

The intersection of the parallels is the solution of the system

```
a'x+b'y+c'-r=0
a"x+b"y+c"-r=0,
```

given by Cramer's rule

```
    |c'-r  b'| / |a'  b'|         |a'  c'-r| / |a'  b'|
u = |c"-r  b"| / |a"  b"|,    v = |a"  c"-r| / |a"  b"|
```

and the coordinates of the projections are simply given by

```
x' = x - a (a'u+b'v+c)
y' = y - b (a'u+b'v+c)

x" = x - a (a"u+b"v+c)
y" = y - b (a"u+b"v+c)
```

Comment: If you need further help, comment here.

Comment: Hi @YvesDaoust, thank for the answer. I believe this does not respond to my question as I do not know the centre point and I do not need it. Rory Daulton pointed out the problem, I need to redefine conditions 5 and 6 to state that the drawn radii are perpendicular to both lines. I will reformulate my questions asap. Do you agree?

Comment: @J.Serra: you don't need to "keep" the center point, but it naturally appears in the resolution. Now if you disdain easy answers, it's your choice. By the way, this approach shows that there are exactly four solutions.

Comment: Given conditions 4 and 5 why do you have  four solutions @YvesDaoust?

Comment: @J.Serra: ok, if constraints are given, there are less than 4 solutions.